# To move data like videos media picture etc from internal memory of Lyf wind. 1 to external 32 GB SD card.?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, apk, zip

I bought a new Lyf ls-5010 on 15 Aug 2016 . in it all setting of picture camera browser are set to internal 4gb it shows no space while capture photo or download something. No I inserted a 32 GB Samsung sd card . but no options to move data from internal memory to SD card. And to change default storage internal to SD card. I bought a 32gb card it only show 28.80 GB space.

Comment: Related: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526) and [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm not knowledgeable about your specific device, but you need to move the "Photos" app itself to the SD card, not the data by itself. Go to Application Manager, find Photos, open it, and you should see a box that says "Move to SD card". Just tap the box, and wait for the app to show "Application moved to SD card", with that same box now reading "Move to device storage". Be patient, especially if you have a lot of stuff in the file. It can take a little while to move all those files. Now all your photos, videos, etc, should go directly to the SD card. Hope you're device works that way.